# tricontourf breaking when contouring over 0 point in polar plot

Tags: python, cartopy, contourf, visual-glitch

I am trying to plot a tricontourf on a polar plot, however it seems that it glitches out when plotting over the 0 longitude point.

[image: glitched]

It's clear when plotting as a scatter plot that the points are just fine.
[image: not glitched]

Furthermore, when plotting the tricontourf in other locations not containing 0 longitude it works just fine.
[image: not glitched 2]

Here is the code for the tricontourf and scatter plot respectively:

```
    axes.tricontourf(prediction['Longitude'], prediction['Latitude'], prediction['Measurement'], levels = np.linspace(0, 2, 50), cmap='viridis', zorder=10)
    axes.scatter(prediction['Longitude'], prediction['Latitude'], c=prediction['Measurement'], cmap='viridis', zorder=10, norm = plt.Normalize(0, 2),s=10)
```

In addition, [here are the data points centred on 0 lon, 62 lat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MR0OHAcjhYxzPiuvKMY8MufJxLRX3-Yr/view?usp=sharing) and [these are the ones centred on -90 lon, 62 lat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uA8jXCwJtTaFqVtaIYE8SeYMJVMmnokX/view?usp=sharing).

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone wondering: the solution is to convert the longitudes from 0-360 to -180-180. I achieved this by the following two lines of code:

```
prediction['Longitude'] = (prediction['Longitude'] + 180) % 360 - 180
prediction = prediction.sort_values('Longitude')
```

[image: fixed]